# MongoDB connection pool is not working properly in Spring application

Tags: mongodb

We have created a Spring based application which is interacting with MongoDB as back end. We are using MongoTemplate to initiate connections.While running the application , we are experiencing connection time outs with below error,

com.mongodb.DBPortPool$ConnectionWaitTimeOut: Connection wait timeout after 1500 ms

We have changed below parameters, but no luck.

```
connections-per-host
connect-timeout
max-wait-time
```

Our observation is that , whenever we experience the timeouts , nubmer of open connections remains the same all the time even before and after the timeouts.

Can you please help me to pin point an issue ?

Comment: Were there any network disruptions during that time? You can check by taking the TCP dumps